# Degree Wheel Label Direction

Tags: diagrams

I'm new in latex development and I've found this code to make a degree wheel :

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{eurosym} % écriture du €
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
%\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

% Define a few constants for easy configuration
\def\radius{2cm}
\def\onedegrad{1.8cm}
\def\fivedegrad{1.75cm}
\def\tendegrad{1.7cm}
\def\labelrad{1.6cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]

  % adding a subtle gray tone to add a bit of "personality"
  \shade[shading=radial, inner color=white, outer color=gray!15] (0,0) circle (\radius);

  \draw (0,0) circle (\radius);
  \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (.02mm);
  \node[draw, circle, inner sep=.2mm] (a) at (0,0) {};

  % helper lines
  %\foreach \x in {-16, 90} \draw[very thick, gray!40] (a) -- (\x:\radius);

  % main lines
  \foreach \x in {0,...,359} \draw (\x:\onedegrad) -- (\x:\radius);

  % labels and longer lines at every 10 degrees
  \foreach \x in {0,10,...,350}
  {
    \node[scale=1.4, rotate=\x*-1] at (360-\x+90:\labelrad) {\x};
    \draw (\x:\tendegrad) -- (\x:\radius);
  };

  % lines at every 5 degrees
  \foreach \x in {0,5,...,355}  \draw (\x:\fivedegrad) -- (\x:\radius);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I just have some trouble to change the label direction : I'd like to have it in counter clockwise sens! I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuT1h.jpg) and I want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h4ls.jpg). Any idea?

Thanks

iOS 10.15.4

MacTeX 2020 Distribution

Working with texmaker

Comment: please have a look if the answer meets your requirement

Comment: request accept answer by clicking the tickmark on the left side

Answer (score 2):

@beardedIntern

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{eurosym} % écriture du €
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
%\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
    
    % Define a few constants for easy configuration
    \def\radius{2cm}
    \def\onedegrad{1.8cm}
    \def\fivedegrad{1.75cm}
    \def\tendegrad{1.7cm}
    \def\labelrad{1.6cm}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    
    % adding a subtle gray tone to add a bit of "personality"
    \shade[shading=radial, inner color=white, outer color=gray!15] (0,0) circle (\radius);
    
    \draw (0,0) circle (\radius);
    \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (.02mm);
    \node[draw, circle, inner sep=.2mm] (a) at (0,0) {};
    
    % helper lines
    %\foreach \x in {-16, 90} \draw[very thick, gray!40] (a) -- (\x:\radius);
    
    % main lines
    \foreach \x in {0,...,359} \draw (\x:\onedegrad) -- (\x:\radius);
    
    % labels and longer lines at every 10 degrees
    \foreach \x in {0,10,...,350}
    {
        \node[scale=1.4, rotate=0] at (\x:\labelrad) {\x};
        \draw (\x:\tendegrad) -- (\x:\radius);
    };
    
    % lines at every 5 degrees
    \foreach \x in {0,5,...,355}  \draw (\x:\fivedegrad) -- (\x:\radius);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that pinging a user with `@...` works only in comments, not in questions and answers.

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!